# How do I manipulate trix-editor to stop resizing after pressing after enter 4 times in a row

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, trix

How to adjust the css in a trix-editor so that I can change its style wherein it would stop resizing after pressing enter few times.

```
<div class="bg-white flex flex-wrap self-end items-center w-full text-xl">
        <!--    <input type="text" class="flex-auto appearance-none text-base p-2" placeholder="Write a message..."> -->
<VueTrix class="flex-auto appearance-none text-base p-2" @keypress.enter="sendMessage" v-model="editorContent" plloreaceholder="Press shift + enter to send your message" localStoragem ipsum/>
</div>
```

This is the a url to the video attachment : 
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/496820557627654174/646552238126399489/Blacktrail_-_Chat_Feature_-_Google_Chrome_2019-11-20_11-23-51.mp4

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be: Configure in the **tailwind.config.js** a custom [maxHeight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height/#app)

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        maxHeight: {
            'four-lines': '96px'
         }
    }
}
```

The class will be: `.max-h-four-lines`